# How to dynamically resolve domains?

Tags: dnsmasq

I've got a zone `.default.svc.cluster.local` with a separate server for it, but I don't want to type all that.

Instead, I want to type `XXX.localhost` to get to the `XXX.default.svc.cluster.local`.

I've been thinking of using `naptr-record` of `dnsmasq` for that, but its syntax drives me mad. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

A common solution is to configure your systems  with an (extra) [search domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_domain).

The domain search list is used by a resolver to create a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) from a relative name, i.e. when you type `somehost` and that can't be foun (there is for example no such entry in your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))) the resolver will attempt to find if a  `somehost.default.svc.cluster.local.` FQDN exists  by appending the default.svc.cluster.local search domain. If it does it will behave as if you had entered `somehost.default.svc.cluster.local.`

The relative name can't contain a `.` dot and a domain search list with multiple domains may not always work as you'd hope either.

---

Regarding your use of `.local` DNS name:

- if you want to ***obfuscate your domain*** use the reserved `example.com.` or similar domains.
- Please do not use the `.local` TLD your for internal DNS records, but only for its [intended purpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local).
- For internal DNS records, please use a subdomain under your own domain, (or a dedicated domain you actually own) instead.
- Do not add '.local' to your search domain

Comment: `local` domain is used by kubernetes cluster. i don't think i can change that.